# Merge two DataFrames by combining duplicates and concatenating nonduplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-merge

I have two DataFrames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],
             'B':[3,4]})
    A   B
0   1   3
1   2   4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,2,1],
             'C':[5,6,7]})


    A   C
0   3   5
1   2   6
2   1   7
```

and I want to merge in a way that the column 'A' add the different values between DataFrames but merge the duplicates.

Desired output:

```
  A   B   C
0 3   NaN 5 
1 2   4   6
2 1   3   7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combine_first`:

```
df2 = df2.combine_first(df)
```

Output:

```
   A    B  C
0  1  3.0  5
1  2  4.0  6
2  3  NaN  7
```

Comment: Thanks, but my exemple was wrong: column A of df2 is not in the same order that column A of df. I just updated the question.

Comment: @CarolVieira Try it with: `df.merge(df2, on='A', how='outer').sort_values(by='A', ascending=False)`

Comment: It works, thanks!  df2.merge(df,how='left', on='A') also works

Comment: @CarolVieira If you expect all `df.A` values to also be in `df2.A`, that also works too.